# How to determine specific JSON objects in array sent by API? Ionic 4 Project btw

Tags: mysql, json, api, rest, ionic-framework

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Phtfp.png)

How can i get the details of the json object in an array sent by my API by a simple button click? For example, assume that there is a buy now button on each card of the products, and when i click on the buy now button on the men's polo card, it would get the details of the men's polo record as well as perform a simple multiplication by quantity entered by user. The cards are pulled from my REST API.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. This forum is not for free freelancer hiring! You can use Upwork instead. Here, you can post your trials or bugs, and some pals might give you a hand with it, but certainly not with an entire feature.

Comment: Please Check How to Ask on Stackoverflow: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask
Share Your code.

Comment: Please post code of what you have tried so far.